# Brunch isn´t showing info about compilation errors

Tags: brunch

I´ve been using Brunch since June. I remember that, when you had a compilation error on jsx for example, if you had brunch running in watch mode, it would show you in which line do you have the error.

But since an specific update that i don't remember, it only shows a message like this:

```
29 Dec 07:50:15 - error: Compiling of app/components/AsciiFacesList.jsx failed.
29 Dec 07:50:15 - error: Compiling of app/components/AsciiFacesList.jsx failed.
```

Without knowing what's wrong. I added the -d flag to my npm command so it's like:

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "brunch watch -d --server",...
```

But even with that, doesn't show additional information like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install brunch from the master branch on github.

https://github.com/brunch/brunch

This issue is already fixed by brunch team and brunch now shows the errors with description.

We have to install from master until this fix will be released with a new version of brunch (`>2.9.1`)

Comment: Yes, you´re right. I also asked this in github and obtained the answer. Thank you so much.
[https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1606](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1606)

Comment: New version is just released :)